# Target the li in the array…how do i

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

```
//Setup Navigation
    var MyProButtonArray = ['My Profile','Media','Friends','DM\'s','Fav\'s'];

    $('#MyProfile').click(function(){
        for(var i = 0; i < MyProButtonArray.length; i++)
        $('#MediaContainer').append('<li class="MyProfileNav">' + MyProButtonArray[i] + '</li>');
        $('#MediaContainer').append('<div id="MyProfileContentContainer"></div>');
    });
```

How do I target the `li` button in the generated array so that I can setup a click handler? 
I need to be able to make click handlers for each button generated in the array, and have them load content into `MyProfileContentContainer`. How do I do this?